# Why PESSIMISTIC_WRITE JPA Lock is not working as expected?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, locking

I have two instances of same spring boot application running. Now if the first server fetches one row from the database and process it and while processing it second server also fetches the same row and start processing it. But that should not be the case. Only one of the server should fetch it, process it and then update the row.

I am trying to develop this using JPA Locks but for some reason it is not working.

Here's my repository interface:

```
@Repository
public interface StudentRepository extends CrudRepository<Student,Integer> {

@Transactional
    @Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
    @Query(value = "SELECT s FROM Student s WHERE s.percentage is null AND s.status = false ORDER BY s.rollid ASC LIMIT 1")
    public Student findFirstStudentWithFalseStatusAndNullPercentage();

}
```

Can someone help me out with it?

P.S: I am using MySQL Database

EDIT:

So, basically I am using Kafka and spring boot. The first task is to fetch the object from the database. For that I have a function which will get called after every 2 seconds (used Scheduled annotation). Then this function will fetch the student object (row) from the MySQL DB using a controller that I have defined. Code for the controller:

```
@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
    public Student getStudent(){
        return studentRepository.findFirstStudentWithFalseStatusAndNullPercentage();
    }
```

This function will return the student object fetched to the function from where it was called and then that function will update the status of student object to `True` using JPA again. Initially it will be `False` for all rows and it represents if the object is being processed or not. Once it is set to `True`, the kafka will come into the picture where it will process the object and once it has processed, a thread will update the object in the database and set the status to `False` again.

Do let me know if any more clarification is needed, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This only works in combination with a Transaction that supports the isolation
eg:

```
@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
public void log(String message){
    someRepository.findFirstStudentWithFalseStatusAndNullPercentage()
}
```

see https://www.baeldung.com/spring-transactional-propagation-isolation

Both Transactions that should be "used" by the lock need to be marked with an isolation level

Your `Transactional` annotation needs to be aboth a Method that executes Code ans not in your Repository.

Comment: I added `Transactional` over my controller method from where I am calling the repository function, but still it is not working!

Comment: What exactly do you expect to happen ? Can you show all your Code?

Comment: As far as I understand your post now is that you want your Scheduler to only run in one Instance of your applion. Pessimistic locking however is to prevent concurrent Updates in your Database. Both Schedulers will still be running and accessing Data. You might need to take a look at Schedlock https://www.baeldung.com/shedlock-spring .  If you want to continue using Pesimistic locking you need to share more of your Code. I am however not sure you will achieve a satisfying result wit Pesimistic locking and your problem.